# Tensorflow Keras Shape mismatch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, training-data, mnist

While trying to implement a standard MNIST digit recognizer that many tutorials use to introduce you to neural networks, I'm encountering the error

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (1,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (28, 10)).
```

I would like to use `from_tensor_slices` to process the data, since I want to apply the code to another problem where the data comes from a CSV file. Anyway, here is the code producing the error in the line `model.fit(...)`

```
import tensorflow as tf

train_dataset, test_dataset = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_images, train_labels = train_dataset
train_images = train_images/255.0
train_dataset_tensor = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))

num_of_validation_data = 10000
validation_data = train_dataset_tensor.take(num_of_validation_data)
train_data = train_dataset_tensor.skip(num_of_validation_data)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), 
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(train_data, batch_size=50, epochs=5)

performance = model.evaluate(validation_data)
```

I don't understand where the shape `(28, 10)` of the logits comes from, I thought I was flattening the image, essentially making a 1D vector out of the 2D image? How can I prevent the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```py
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

x_train = x_train[..., tf.newaxis]
x_test = x_test[..., tf.newaxis]

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (x_train, y_train)).shuffle(10000).batch(32)
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test)).batch(32)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), 
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(train_ds)
```

Comment: I would like to use `from_tensor_slices`, since I want to user it for a different dataset later.

Comment: I changed my answer. Take a look

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works, but the lines with `tf.newaxis` do not seem to be necessary. The addition of `.batch(32)` does the trick. Can you explain why this is needed?

Comment: As written in documentaion, you can't define `batch_size` in `fit` function, if you are using datasets or generators. In this case you should batch the dataset the way above. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly